# Copying only non blank rows and pasting to the first blank row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm super new to VB so apologies if this is ridiculously simple. I've got a macro to transfer an order form to a continuous register of orders.

Here's the code I've got:

```
Range("B2:X2").Select 
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Register of Orders").Select
Range("B9").Select 
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Instead of Range B2:X2 I need to select all non blank rows. And instead of Range B9 I need to select the first blank row at the bottom of the register.

I have had a look at a few answers on here and tried to use the code suggested, but I always got an error saying Expected End Sub.

Comment: Can you give us the full code? You just want to copy all sheet except empty rows?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Can you maybe add an image of the order form and the "bottom of the register". I dont understand how it looks like. Is it a new worksheet or the same? I am sure we can help.
The error "Expected End Sub" occurs if you copy code into an area, that is not wrapped by "Sub MakroName()  .....your code.... End Sub

Comment: I'm apparently not allowed to add images. The order form and register are on separate worksheets

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult one to even attempt answering because we can't see your spreadsheet.

To help you with the copy the following code may assist. The code will copy data from B6 through to X6 of Sheet1 (you can change this to the sheet of your data so long as it isn't in the same sheet).

The code will copy data from sheet1 to the "Register of Orders" one column at a time ignoring blanks values.

```
Sub test_copy_ignoring_blanks()

    Sheets("Register of Orders").Select
    Range("A1").select 'Data will be pasted To Cell A1 moving 1 column position

    'Select the sheet where your data is I'm imagining this is sheet 1
    Sheets(1).Select


    Dim starting_column As Long
    Dim ending_column As Long

    'Set the starting and ending columns
    Range("X6").Select
    ending_column = ActiveCell.Column
    Range("B6").Select
    starting_column = ActiveCell.Column

    'Loop through for the copy
    For counter = starting_column To ending_column
        Cells(6, counter).Select
        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        ' The cell is not empty so copy it and paste it to Regist Order
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Register of Orders").Select
        'Select the Range you want to paste it in
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        'Move the cursor one to the right
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Sheets(1).Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Would that not copy and paste over previous orders already in the register, if it starts from A1 every time?

Comment: @HannahThorley You can modify the cell to your desire location. It's impossible to know where you need the data to go.

Answer (score 0):

I basicly copied the firs guy answer and applyed it to rows insted of columns

```
Sub Copia_Cola_Sem_Linhas_Vazia()
Sheets("Planilha1").Select
'Name of the sheet where the data is
Range("A1").Select '
'Select the sheet where your data is I'm imagining this is sheet 1
Dim starting_column As Long
Dim ending_column As Long
Dim c2 As Long
'Choose the Range of the Last row
Range("A32").Select
ending_row = ActiveCell.Row
'Choose the Range of the first row
Range("C1").Select
starting_row = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
'Choose Where you want Start Pasting your data
c2 = 1

'Loop through for the copy
For counter = starting_row To ending_row
    Cells(counter, 7).Select
    '7 is the column where you wanna check if the data is empity or not
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Planilha2").Select
    'Name of the sheet where you want paste yor data
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c2).Select
    'Select the Range you want to paste it in
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Move the cursor one down
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Sheets(1).Select
    c2 = c2 + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```